# Ripples in the passband of a SAW filter

Tags: filter

In SAW Filters we have a phenomenon called TTE, Triple Transit Echos. How does this phenomenon render
 inband ripples different than in a Chebyshev filter?

Am I also correct to assume that the amplitude ripples in both of these filters also indicate the necessity of existence of phase distortion? , i.e. it is impossible to have amplitude ripples with zero phase distortion in any of these two filters

Comment: Staggered BP filters carefully selected achieve a broader BPF with controlled ripple and group delays but steepest skirts.  The echos or Return Loss of each filter contribute to attenuation with load .   The Bessel Filters are also lowest Q and provide the lowest group delay distortion or best linear phase shift but least steep skirts.